# how do we append some constant text to a symbol and string column? Finally we should have a list of symbols and a list of string

Tags: kdb

I have a table say example below

```
n: 30;  // Number of rows in the table
tab:([] date: .z.d - n?30; ranks: n?100; sym: n?`AAPL`MSFT`GOOGL; group_name_symbol:n?`US_HOLIDAY`SPCL_CAL_DATE ; group_name_string:n?("FIRST_3rd_FRI";"QTR_3rd_FRI";"FIRST_6rd_FRI") ;price: "f"$n?100.5; recv_time: n?10:00:00.000 + n?10000000; is_active: "b"$n?1 0);
tab:update group_name_symbol:` from tab where sym=`AAPL;
tab:update group_name_string:` from tab where sym=`GOOGL;
```

[image]

Now I want append some fixed text to the column group_name_symbol and group_name_string.
And I want to keep appending new fixed text evetime to the column whenever required. So new update statement for different fixed text.

so the final output will look like when i run separate update query

```
update group_name_symbol:`CSMT from tab where ranks=92  //append and not override 
update group_name_string:`THN from tab where ranks=19  //append and not override 
update group_name_string:`KRL from tab where ranks=19  //append and not override
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure you columns are lists of lists from the start or you will get errors

`enlist each` added when defining:

```
q)n: 30;  // Number of rows in the table
q)tab:([] date: .z.d - n?30; ranks: n?100; sym: n?`AAPL`MSFT`GOOGL; 
          group_name_symbol:enlist each n?`US_HOLIDAY`SPCL_CAL_DATE ; 
          group_name_string:enlist each n?("FIRST_3rd_FRI";"QTR_3rd_FRI";"FIRST_6rd_FRI") ;
          price: "f"$n?100.5; recv_time: n?10:00:00.000 + n?10000000; 
          is_active: "b"$n?1 0);
```

Again when emptying rows care needed to have correct empty lists:

```
q)tab:update group_name_symbol:count[i]#enlist `$() from tab where sym=`AAPL;
q)tab:update group_name_string:count[i]#() from tab where sym=`GOOGL;
```

```
q)5 sublist tab
date       ranks sym   group_name_symbol group_name_string price    recv_time    is_active
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023.06.13 76    GOOGL ,`US_HOLIDAY      ()                7.504439 12:35:24.923 1
2023.05.30 13    MSFT  ,`US_HOLIDAY      ,"FIRST_3rd_FRI"  38.08953 11:54:05.027 0
2023.05.27 87    MSFT  ,`SPCL_CAL_DATE   ,"FIRST_3rd_FRI"  21.29572 11:54:05.027 1
2023.05.26 11    AAPL  `symbol$()        ,"FIRST_3rd_FRI"  33.82582 10:23:06.750 0
2023.06.13 66    AAPL  `symbol$()        ,"FIRST_6rd_FRI"  52.37666 10:36:25.423 0
```

```
q)meta tab
c                | t f a
-----------------| -----
date             | d
ranks            | j
sym              | s
group_name_symbol| S     // Lists of symbols goes from s --> S
group_name_string|       // Lists of strings goes from C --> blank
price            | f
recv_time        | t
is_active        | b
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right

`,` needs to be wrapped in `()` to use it as append in a qsql query:

```
q)tab:update group_name_symbol:group_name_symbol(,)\:`CSMT from tab where ranks=11
q)tab:update group_name_string:group_name_string(,)\:enlist "THN" from tab where ranks=76
q)tab:update group_name_string:group_name_string(,)\:enlist "KRL" from tab where ranks=76
```

The result:

```
q)5 sublist tab
date       ranks sym   group_name_symbol group_name_string price    recv_time    is_active
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023.06.13 76    GOOGL ,`US_HOLIDAY      ("THN";"KRL")     7.504439 12:35:24.923 1
2023.05.30 13    MSFT  ,`US_HOLIDAY      ,"FIRST_3rd_FRI"  38.08953 11:54:05.027 0
2023.05.27 87    MSFT  ,`SPCL_CAL_DATE   ,"FIRST_3rd_FRI"  21.29572 11:54:05.027 1
2023.05.26 11    AAPL  ,`CSMT            ,"FIRST_3rd_FRI"  33.82582 10:23:06.750 0
2023.06.13 66    AAPL  `symbol$()        ,"FIRST_6rd_FRI"  52.37666 10:36:25.423 0
```

Comment: Thank you Rianoc, that was exactly I was looking for. Appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your symbol-atoms column into a nested-symbols column you would first have to do:

```
update enlist each group_name_symbol from `tab
```

then you could do:

```
q)update group_name_symbol:(group_name_symbol,'`CSMT) from tab where ranks=87
date       ranks sym   group_name_symbol group_name_string price     recv_tim..
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------..
2023.06.16 87    GOOGL `US_HOLIDAY`CSMT  `                 55.25425  11:32:21..
2023.06.06 63    GOOGL ,`US_HOLIDAY      `                 19.68259  10:38:48..
```

For your string column you should be setting blanks like so:

```
tab:update group_name_string:count[i]#enlist"" from tab where sym=`GOOGL;
```

Then you can similarly append

```
q)update enlist each group_name_string from `tab
q)update group_name_string:(group_name_string,\:enlist"THN") from tab where ranks=62
date       ranks sym   group_name_symbol group_name_string     price     recv..
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------..
2023.06.16 87    GOOGL US_HOLIDAY        ,""                   55.25425  11:3..
2023.06.06 63    GOOGL US_HOLIDAY        ,""                   19.68259  10:3..
2023.06.20 62    MSFT  SPCL_CAL_DATE     ("QTR_3rd_FRI";"THN") 56.43337  12:4..
2023.05.26 42    GOOGL US_HOLIDAY        ,""                   7.079031  11:5..
```

Comment: Thank you Terry! Appreciate your quick response.